# How to define an id for the added rows in a table in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have to add rows to a table dynamically,i can add rows and delete.But how can i define an id for the added rows to write something inside of them or add some links ?

Comment: Please add more information and the code you're using.

Comment: How are you adding the rows now?

Comment: i get some informations from an xml file,i have to add rows to a table,and i have to write these informations on the added rows.So,i want to define id's for the added rows and write these informations.

Comment: function addRow() {

        var root = document.getElementById('mytab').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
        var rows = root.getElementsByTagName('tr');
        var clone = cloneEl(rows[rows.length - 1]);
        root.appendChild(clone);

    }
------------
function cloneEl(el) {
        var clo = el.cloneNode(true);
        return clo;
    }

Answer (score 1):

If it is always the last row, your could use jQuery and something like :

```
$('table tr:last')
```

Answer (score 0):

You would have to add the new id number to the tr when you create the row. If you're using jQuery you could do something like this:

```
$('#btnAdd').click(function () {
        var num = $('tr').length;
        var newNum = new Number(num + 1);
        $('table').find('tr:first-child').append().after('<tr id="row-' + newNum + '"><td>Some new data</td></tr>');   
    });
```

This would count how many `<tr>` you have and add this as the highest number to your new `<tr>`. So if you have 5 `<tr>`, then the newest would be `id="row-6"` etc.

I haven't tested that code, but that SHOULD work. You may need to play around with the insert line a bit to get it exactly where you want it. But that should be starting point.